# VSCode + Python: automatically add whitespace after a comma

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like VSCode to automatically input whitespaces after commas or other characters in order to have my **Python** code in order. Is there an option like **TypeScript › Format:Insert Space After Semicolon In For Statements**  or **CSS › Format: Space Around Selector Separator**.

If not natively available, how do I add this option?

I tried looking in the Preferences, and also attempted custom Keybindings with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean formatter? You can add this in the settings.json, then when you save the file, it will format automatically.

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
```